# Videos not playing properly after recent update in November 2024

Tags: updates, video

In September, installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS on my new ASUS laptop without hiccups. Two weeks ago, after yet another update to the software, SOME but not all videos show up as rubbish (see image). The same video sometimes plays correctly and at other times not. I believe the update caused this. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.[Screen shot of garbled video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK0NS.jpg)

Comment: this sounds like missing codecs and might be solved by installing them,do you have VLC installed on your system?

Comment: Is November 2024 a prediction?

Comment: @trond hansen: Thank you for responding. Yes, I have VLC installed, and can play any of MY OWN videos without difficulty.  But how can I use VLC to play others' videos (e.g. on Youtube)? The available instructions on "making VLC the default video player" don't seem to apply to 22.04LTS.  Also, "sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras" doesn't solve the problem.  I don't care about that, if I can install VLC as the default even for external videos.